# Performance of ISNULL in SELECT statement

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with the following columns,

```
ID(int),
RegardingContactID(int),
RegardingAccountId(int),
RegardingIncidentID(int),
RegardingType(varchar)
```

`RegardingType` can be "Contact", "Account", "Incident"

Basically I'd like to abstract all the `RegardingXXXID` columns like this:

```
 SELECT 
     ID,
     ISNULL(RegardingContactID, ISNULL(RegardingAccountId, RegardingIncidentID)) AS RegardingID,
     RegardingType
```

This seems to work as intended but the `ISNULL` does not appear to be performant with large datasets.

Is there a more elegant/performant way to achieve this?

Comment: Why do you think `isnull` that is the cause for bad performance?

Comment: Because I ran the SELECT without the ISNULL returning each of the ID columns in separate queries and compared it to the query above using ISNULL

Comment: Don't compare with three different queries. Compare with returning the values as three columns in the same query.

Comment: i would say try both isnull and COALESCE and compare the performance or post the execution plan here

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use `COALESCE` instead of `ISNULL`

```
SELECT ID,
       COALESCE(RegardingContactID, RegardingAccountId, RegardingIncidentID) AS RegardingID,
```

Comment: what made you believe that COALESCE is better than Isnull

Comment: @NeerajPrasadSharma. Execute `COALESCE` in one stage have better performance as a bit than execute `ISNULL` twice.

Comment: `COALESCE` is ANSI standard SQL, too, whereas `ISNULL` is a MS-specific extension.

Comment: I know Collacse is Ansi standard, as far as performance is issue as per question. in some cases isnull can be better or in some cases COALESCE is better, or then can be at par.

Aaron Bertrand has covered most of the cases 
http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2689/deciding-between-coalesce-and-isnull-in-sql-server/

Answer (score 1):

If we dig a bit more, `COALESCE` is basically transformed to `CASE` statement by SQL Server engine into something like that:

```
select case 
      when RegardingContactID is not null then RegardingContactID
      when RegardingAccountId is not null then RegardingAccountId
      when RegardingIncidentID is not null then RegardingIncidentID
      end AS RegardingID
```

But you may end with this:

```
select case 
      when RegardingType = 'Contact' then RegardingContactID
      when RegardingType = 'Account' then RegardingAccountId
      when RegardingType = 'Incident' then RegardingIncidentId
      end as RegardingID
```

which, imho, is more relevant to your original target.

PS. ISNULL perfomance is quite not bad. It's just the evaluation chain (3 times) may cause perfomance slowdown.

Answer (score 0):

As the other said, [COALESCE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/coalesce-transact-sql) is more elegant and might perform better.

But regarding the performance I recommend to benchmark both approaches, it is the only way how to realize it. Also another approach might be to select all 3 columns and choose the right one in application which processes query result.